# Can't change wallpaper - Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, desktop-background

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 on my personal laptop, but I'm unable to change the wallpaper. I used to do it by right-clicking the desktop and then changing the desktop properties.

Now the right-click does not work (nothing happens When I open the system Settings, I can see all options but not "Desktop". Even when I open "Appearance" no tab relates to changing the wallpaper.

I'm wondering if I had changed or uninstalled some module that related to the Desktop configuration.

Any clues?

Comment: My guess is yes, you probably have changed/modified (even if not uninstalled) some part of your system that has caused it.  I would look in your `history` ie. commands executed, esp. whilst using `sudo` for clues as to what you did, or logs for removed packages.  It's possible you followed some advice intended for another desktop/release to do something, and caused `xfwm4` (window manager for xfce) to be replaced by another package; which may not been it was uninstalled, just you made another wm run in it's place.  Viewing your `history` should show this if you did it with command.

Comment: • If you run `inxi -Fxxxz` and post that output here [by editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1159101/edit), we will know quite a bit about your system. • If you don't have "privacy" worries, upload your *.bash_history* somewhere, so people can know if any recent terminal commands could be responsible: installing *pastebinit* is useful for this. • Another possible issue is the inappropriate use of `sudo` which may result in some of the files meant to be owned by you now being owned by *root*: the output of `find . '!' -user $USER -ls` when run from your home folder would help.